# How to fix 'printing a single number from a Python list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a variable from a python list, but my code only returns the brackets of the list. Is there something I am doing wrong?

I have tried to remove the quotation marks, but that does not work either.

The list I want to retrieve values from:

```
date = [4, 1, 2000]
```

What I am doing:

```
print(date[0])
```

What it returns:

```
[
```

I was thinking that it does behave like this because maybe Python sees this as a string. However, while mapping and listing the list it still gives me the same error. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a list which I assume it is, it will work

```
date = [4, 1, 2000]
print(date[0])
#4
```

But if it is a string it won't work and show up what you saw

```
date = "[4, 1, 2000]"
print(date[0])
```

So check out the format of date